# Migration from RXJS 5 to 6 - IntervalObservable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I updated from RXJS 5.x to RXJS 6.2.2 and have a problem with solving a migration error.

Are there no more IntervalObservables in RXJS 6? I used IntervalObservable in the following angular component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IntervalObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-time-display',
  templateUrl: './date-time-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-time-display.component.css']
})
export class DateTimeDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  today = Date.now();

  ngOnInit() {
    IntervalObservable.create(1000)
    // .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.today = Date.now();
      });
  }
}
```

When i run either 'ng serve' or 'ng build' I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable' in 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\IMA\Porsche_lack\git\webapp\porsche-lack-tracking\src\app\date-time-display'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/observable/IntervalObservable'.
```

FYI: I ran the command `rxjs-tslint auto update rules` before and it did not find any migration problems!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000).pipe(
       takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.today = Date.now();
    });
```

[rxjs 6 interval](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() =>
  // code goes here
);
```

Comment: has not worked : interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: Remove Observable and import 'interval' directly. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs interval as of angular 8.

```js
  import { interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';

  ngOnInit() {
    const TEN_MINUTES = 600000;

    interval(TEN_MINUTES).subscribe(() => {
      this.refreshSession();
    });
  }
```